# How to set a box at 100% height with dynamic content

Tags: html

I am trying to set up a registration page where the white block will remain at 100% of the page, even when someone clicks on show terms and conditions (which expend the page by a lot. (I put height at 600 px to have the box, as if I put 100% the box stops above First Name *

Anyone can help me with that problem? Thank you.

```
<body style="background: #f2f2f2;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;-moz- 
osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;">


<div style="max-width: 960px; height: 600px; padding: 15px;background: 
#ffffff;border-radius: 5px;margin:8px auto;font-family: Open 
Sans,Helvetica,Arial;font-size: 15px;color: #666;">

<div id="textbox">
<p class="alignleft"><img src=""/></p>
<p class="alignright">[su_button 
url="" size="8" radius="0" 
style="flat"]Client Login[/su_button]</p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div style="text-align: left; font-weight: 600; font-size: 26px; border- 
bottom: solid 3px #eeeeee;">

</div>

[ultimatemember form_id=57]
```

Comment: Hi! I noticed that you are not quite too experienced with html/css and i advice you to take a look at w3schools tutorials. They are simple enough for starters and you should soon realize what you are doing "wrong". Such as not using ids nor classes on your elements and not inlining css or externally writing your css to another file... good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `height: 600px;` put `overflow: hidden;` to that `div` element.